# Transformar um Array de Strings em Objeto com reduce

Tags: javascript

Olá, preciso transformar um array de Strings que possui um pipe dividindo os valores:

```
const values = ['val1|val2|val3', 'val12|val22|val32', 'val123|val223|val323']
```

E preciso que esse array se transforme em um objeto de Arrays que concatenam os valores de mesma posição:

```
resultado = { pos1: ['val1', 'val12', 'val123'], pos2: ['val2', 'val22', 'val223',... }
```

Tentei fazer com reduce:

```
values.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const [valPos1, valPos2, valPos3] = value.split('|')

  acc.pos1.push(valPos1)
  acc.pos2.push(valPos2)
  acc.pos2.push(valPos3)

  return acc
}, {})
```

O problema é que o acc.pos1, acc.pos2 e acc.pos3 ainda não existem, e dá erro no push.
Uma solução seria fazer a verificação antes, por exemplo:

```
acc.pos1 = acc.pos1 || {}
```

Mas ficaria de uma forma muito suja fazer isso pra todos, e um loop dentro do reduce também não seria uma boa opção.
Alguma sugestão de como posso fazer?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 4):

Não precisa de muita coisa, um for básico resolve

```js
const values = ['val1|val2|val3', 'val12|val22|val32', 'val123|val223|val323'];
const resultados = {};

for (let i = 0, j = values.length; i < j; i++) {
    resultados['pos' + (i + 1)] = values[i].split('|');
}

console.log(resultados);
```

Veja que ficou bastante simples e pelo que entendi sua dificuldade nem foi como "converter", mas sim definir a chave pos1, pos2, etc no novo objeto. Isso é porque se o valor da chave é dinâmica e você deve usar dessa forma `variavel[chavedinamica]` ao invés de `variavel.chave`, então no código (com ou sem *template string*, porque isso é opcional) você simplesmente faz isso:

```
 resultados['pos' + (i + 1)]
```

Ou se deseja usar template string (o que nesse código não terá vantagem alguma, mas fica ao seu critério):

```
 resultados[`pos${i + 1}`]
```

Recomendo muito que você comece pelo básico aprendendo de fato como funciona a linguagem, a documentação da MDN é muito boa (do meu ponto de vista) para isso, segue um link:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Não há motivos para usar `Array.prototype.map`, `Array.prototype.reduce` e `Object.prototype.fromEntries` nesse problema seu especifico, o problema é simples, pegar valores e jogar em um objeto com chaves próprias, com o um `for(;;)` resolve o problema facilmente, funções como as que citei são úteis em cenários mais específicos.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) não é ferramenta mais adequada para o seu problema pois se trata de um método que retorna um elemento resultante da aplicação uma função redutora a cada elemento dum array. Mas também não impossível realizar o que deseja. Veja o exemplo que faz uso dos métodos [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), que define ou modifica uma propriedade diretamente em um objeto, e [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) que divide uma String em uma array de substrings, divisão baseada em um separador que pode ser uma string ou padrão de expressão regular.

```js
const valores = ['val1|val2|val3', 'val12|val22|val32', 'val123|val223|val323'];

let obj = valores.reduce(function(acc, cur, idx) {
  return Object.defineProperty(acc, `prop${idx + 1}`, {
    enumerable: true,
    value: cur.split('|'),
  })
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Uma abordagem mais simples pode ser obtida com o método [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), que retorna um array dos resultados da aplicação dum callback a cada elemento dum array, nesse caso para cada elemento de `valores` retorna um array chave/valor que será consumido por [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) que transforma uma lista de pares chave-valor em um objeto.

```js
const valores = ['val1|val2|val3', 'val12|val22|val32', 'val123|val223|val323'];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(valores.map((v, i) => [`pos${i+1}`, v.split('|')]));

console.log(obj);
```